# Batch Windows - Replace first column of all csv recursively with grandparent folder name

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need to replace all the values in first column of every csv contained in folders and subfolfers, placing there the name of grandparent folder.
I got this code to get the grandparent foldername in a previous needed step, to place it in the file name. But if I try to place this information in a variable this empties and using it in that line of code was the only way to work it out.
Can you help me modify my code to find and replace the word "XXX" with grandparent folder name?
Thank you in advance

```
@Echo OFF
FOR /D /R %%# in (*) DO (
    PUSHD "%%#"
  FOR %%@ in ("*.csv") DO (
for %%I in (..) DO Ren "%%@" "%%~nI%%~xI_%%~n#_%date:/=%%%~x@"
    )
    POPD
)

Pause&Exit
```

EDIT1: CSV Structure (|)

```
FIELD1|FIELD2|FIELD3|FIELD4|FIELD5|FIELD6|FIELD7|FIELD7|FIELD9|FIELD10|FIELD11|FIELD12|FIELD13|FIELD14|FIELD15
STRINGTOBEREPLACED|A|IT545454|M000000\ABCD|root/SERVER||SQL Service User|Enabled|05/05/2020|ADMIN(root\ADMINS)|ADMIN(root\ADMINS)
STRINGTOBEREPLACED|A|IT545454|M000000\ABCD|root/SERVER||SQL Service User|Enabled|05/05/2020|ADMIN(root\ADMINS)|ADMIN(root\ADMINS)
STRINGTOBEREPLACED|A|IT545454|M000000\ABCD|root/SERVER||SQL Service User|Enabled|05/05/2020|ADMIN(root\ADMINS)|ADMIN(root\ADMINS)
```

Comment: I am not 100% sure what you want here. You say you want to modify the first column of the csv file, but you show code that renames the file itself? You also do not show the expected results nor the original file content or dir structure, so it is unclear what you want.

Comment: Hello, I was just showing how I got the grandparent foldername in a previous step. I need to replace the value of the first column of every csv in my folders and subfolders structure with this value, that change every time the for enters a new folder. I also said that I don't know how to save this value in some variable to be used in a replace after I rename the file. I would like to know if there is a simple way, from this code, to get a code that does all this. I don't know how a folder structure o file structure would make a difference here.

Comment: Can you show what the csv looks like in its current state and how you would like it to be? it is important to see the format.

Comment: I edited my post as you requested, thank you.

Comment: Yes they originally does not have any header, I add it by mergin all the files with it.

Answer (score 0):

Word of caution. This script assumes that you have headers in each file. It is also important to understand that the `csv` files cannot contain `!` as this will not include those characters due to `delayedexpansion` used. The script does not write back to the original file, instead it writes to a temp file, then it will replace the original file. So I suggest you create a test directory structure with some `csv` files and run the script inside it first running it on any actual data files.

Please read each part of the script in order to understan exactly what it does. It is recursing though directories from where the script is located (`%~dp0`) so you need to make sure you place it in the correct point of your path.

```
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /r %%a in (*.csv) do for /d %%i in (%%~dpa..) do (
    set header=
    set "repl=%%~nxi"
    for /f "usebackq delims=" %%x in ("%%~a") do if not defined header set "header=%%x"
    (echo !header!)>"%%~dpatemp.txt"
    for /f "usebackq skip=1 tokens=1* delims=|" %%c in ("%%~a") do (
       set "output=%%~nxi|%%d"
       (echo !output!)>>"%%~dpatemp.txt"
    )
   break>"%%~fa"
   move /Y "%%~dpatemp.txt" "%%~fa"
)
```

Comment: Thank you @Gerhard, this does the job perfectly. I tested it in a test directory and everthing works fine. Many thanks, I'll study your code to get how it works.